# El Arreglo está mostrando símbolos extraños

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

Tengo unos problemas con 2 consultas que traen información de 1 alumno con matricula 000025932.
La primera consulta trae los datos correctamente pero el alumno en su apellido paterno (a_paterno) tiene una Ñ (SALDAÑA) y me esta colocando en vez de Ñ la letra Ã.

Consulta

```
public function createInstitucionalAlumnoAccesos($id_matricula)
{
    if (!isset($this->session->userdata['sess_data']['id_usuario'])) {
        redirect(base_url().'Auth');
    }

    try {
        // Obtengo la informacion del usuario
        $usuario_data = $this->Institutional_alumnos_model->getAlumnoAjax($id_matricula);
        print_r($usuario_data);

        // La funcion tiene mas procesos abajo pero se los borre dejando unicamente la consulta a la Base de Datos
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        show_error($e->getMessage() . ' --- ' . $e->getTraceAsString());
    } //./catch
}
```

Resultado

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [matricula] => 000025932 [FIRST_NAME] => LUIS [MIDDLE_NAME] => MAURICIO [a_paterno] => SALDAÃA [a_materno] => BECERRA [PersonId] => 26046 [estatus] => NUIN [EmailType] => PERS [email_people] => luis2000mau38@gmail.com [PEOPLE_TYPE] => STUD [CURRICULUM] => LA [DEGREE] => LIC ) )
```

La segunda consulta es una duplica de la primer, pero borre las demás operaciones dejando únicamente la consulta la Base de Datos para posteriormente imprimir el resultado y me imprime los datos correctamnete.

> Consulta

```
public function acentos()
{  
    try {
        $id_matricula = "000025932";
        $usuario_data = $this->Institutional_alumnos_model->getAlumnoAjax($id_matricula);
        print_r($usuario_data);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        show_error($e->getMessage() . ' --- ' . $e->getTraceAsString());
    } //./catch
}
```

> Resultado

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [matricula] => 000025932 [FIRST_NAME] => LUIS [MIDDLE_NAME] => MAURICIO [a_paterno] => SALDAÑA [a_materno] => BECERRA [PersonId] => 26046 [estatus] => NUIN [EmailType] => PERS [email_people] => luis2000mau38@gmail.com [PEOPLE_TYPE] => STUD [CURRICULUM] => LA [DEGREE] => LIC ) )
```

Alguien tiene idea de porque me esta trayendo el símbolo raro en la primera consulta o como puedo solucionar ese problema.

Se los agradecería.

Saludos.

Comment: ya lo haz codificado en utf-8?

Comment: ya pero no queda